# High CPU usage by WMIPRVSE.EXE process at regular intervals in Windows

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cpu-usage, limits

I noted eventually at production server with almost 200.000 handle and wmiprvse.exe process with high cpu usage.

The server has approximately 200 processes running on Windows server 2012-R2 (virtualized with VMWare) with 12 processors and 12.4 Gb memory.

I discovered this article:
High CPU usage by WMIPRVSE.EXE process at regular intervals in Windows:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4483874/high-cpu-usage-by-wmiprvse-exe-process

It is quoted that 50000 handle would be a value indicating that there is some problem.

This limit of 50000 must be respected?

Comment: I open this quention in https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0a45dc84-77c0-4b70-ab9f-8d43bc793ed1/high-cpu-usage-by-wmiprvseexe-process-at-regular-intervals-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

You don't really explain if some WMI activity is actually expected, and why.
The Windows support article linked says that wmiprvse.exe will eat CPU **when** collecting performance data **while** a large number of file handles are in use. But as I understand it, for the issue to occur, this data collection must have been triggered in the first place.

Do you happen to have some sort of monitoring going on through WMI on this server ?
If that's so, you might want to try and disable it, and maybe tune the checks done there.

Comment: The WMIPRVSE.EXE process performs OS activities. There is no deliberate action for this. The problem is how to determine if any operating system thresholds have been reached, and the WMIPRVSE.EXE process activity is only a symptom.